# Contar valores se os valores em duas colunas da mesma linha forem especificados

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho duas tabelas no excel, Fornecedores e Histórico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso fazer uma contagem de quantas vezes o fornecedor A cometeu o erro A, o fornecedor A cometeu o erro B... e assim por diante, pensei em montar algo com CONT.SES, mas o valor de FornecedorA e ErroA deveria bater em duas colunas da mesma linha, não estou conseguindo pensar em uma maneira de fazer isso...
Preferia não usar Macro.

Tentei algo assim:

```
=CONT.SES(
  Historico!B:C,
  Fornecedores!B1=Historico!B:B,
  Historico!B:C,
  Fornecedores!A2=Historico!C:C
)
```

Alguma ideia de como posso montar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em sua Planilha de resultado coloque da seguinte maneira em `B2`:

```
=CONT.SES(Historico!B:B;$A1;Historico!C:C;B$1)
```

Arraste para de `B2` para `D2`e veja se funciona, depois arraste para os outros fornecedores adaptando a fórmula.